# Is it possible to resize base64 code representing the image?

Tags: power-automate, power-platform

I am using power autoamte to convert an image in **base64**, and then I put this code in html.
Here is what I do:

1. I convert the original image to base64
2. I put this code in the html content in the <`img src='myBase64'>`
   tag.
3. I convert the html to pdf format

Everything is fine, but when my html file reaches more than 2 mb my flow stops working. This is the limit for this conversion operation.

My question is:
Is it possible to resize the base64 code? I know there are external connectors resize images like Encodian, but I don't want to use them.

I searched on the internet, but without much results.

Thank you in advance